# does context seem to be the best way to manage user auth state for this scenario?

Tags: reactjs

I prefer to use a class-based architecture in my React apps (which means I can't use hooks). I prefer simple state management to ramp up quickly so I don't like to jump into Redux until I need to.

So it seems like my main 2 options for maintaining user auth state would either be to use context or pass a user object through props. Normally I would be biased towards dummy components but for this specific scenario, using context to manage user auth state seems to be the most logical fit.

Does context seem to be the best way to manage user auth state for this scenario?

Comment: It depends if you need the auth data across the application and in deep level components. See this excellent tweet from Michael Jackson on context https://twitter.com/mjackson/status/1195495535483817984?s=19 he says that context is rarerly should be used

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a *necessarily* correct answer here, but in my opinion yes, this is a great use-case for a Context.

Keep in mind that class components can still access a context without the `useContext` hook (I'm not sure whether or not you were implying this). You can do this directly my setting the `YourComponent.ContextType` property, or alternatively write a functional-component based HOC which uses `useContext` and then passes it into the class component directly as a prop.

Comment: thanks bill.  the react context examples that I'm seeing online seem to use an approach of using a reference of someContext.Consumer and someContext.Provider like this exanple: https://alligator.io/react/manage-user-login-react-context/.  how would you differentiate this approach from the approach that you mentioned?

Comment: I guess I just forgot that `<context.Consumer>` is a thing. Thats another totally valid solution. I wouldn't _really_ differentiate it from my suggestions, its just a third way of doing essentially the exact same thing. It just comes down to personal preference at that point.